# Computer won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer is not starting. I have a black screen and it gives me series of beeps. Can some body please let me know what might be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More about Beep codes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test

Answer (score 9):

The beeps usually indicate something is wrong with your hardware (e.g. Hard drive, memory, CPU, etc.) The beeps usually form a pattern (like Morse code) that tell you which one is causing problems... Check your motherboard's manual for the meaning of the beeps... If it's not in there, post which one you're currently using. (Brand, type, etc.)

The link from jer.salamon does offer some overview on the beeps, but on the same page the following is also mentioned:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test#A_word_of_caution_-_POST_beep_codes

> Manufacturers do not all use the same
>   beeps codes and do not seem to observe
>   any standard. It is important before
>   attempting to fix a problem to search
>   for specific information relating to
>   your motherboard and BIOS version.
>   Failure to do this can result in
>   serious damage to a system, as well as
>   wasting time and money.

Answer (score 1):

possibly the reason is ram... if you have more then one ram attached to motherboard you should take out one of them then try to boot again if same thing happens try other rams ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of knowing the exact code (as is discussed in other posts), the odds are usually that there's something wrong with a major component (motherboard, CPU, power supply, RAM), or a component isn't seated correctly.  I advise reseating all connectors, PCI(-e) card, RAM chips, etc, and seeing if that's sufficient to resolve the problem.

If that's no resolution, unplug all the drives, remove all the RAM except the first stick, and see if the problem remains.  If it does, swap in a different stick.  If it still does, attempt to boot the machine with zero sticks installed - pretty much any PC should beep like crazy at you if you try this.  If it doesn't, you're probably looking at a processor or motherboard problem (if it does, you're probably looking at a bad RAM slot which usually means you have to replace the board since a lot of modern boards require RAM inserted into the slots in a specific order...)

But REALLY, the best thing to do would be to figure out the board in the machine and go find the manufacturer's manual which should list the beep codes.  It could even be as simple as a bad video card.